# Getting the stylesheet directory from within the XSL file- for configureable xml location

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xsl file for an xml. The location of the the xml files should be configurable (that's done by configuring the href path to stylesheet in the xml) but the xsl is using some images and some othe javaScript files and need to hav teh path to them. The path is right near the stylesheet file so once I can get the xsl directory I can ge to them.
for example:
in my xml I have:?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href=".\Files\Style\test.xsl">
I want from within the xsl to point to ".\Files\Style" for the images' location
Hoe can I do this

Comment: See the solution to your problem :)

Comment: Hint: In case the provided answer solves the problem, you can *accept* it by clicking on the check mark at the left top of the question. You may also be able to upvote it, depending on the points you've currently got (I think you must have 50 points, in order to have the right to upvote). :)

Comment: thanks,
I still need your help :)
I have an xsl trnafering to a html in my xsl I have a few templates and some java script functions what's the correct way to pass the info to the other templates and to the jScript -is it problematic if I have in teh same fiel 2 templated with match ? cause I didn't manage getting to teh path. It might be a beginner's question but I'm quite new in this area. I appreciate  you help

Comment: This is a new and not very well stated question -- Please, ask it as a separate question, provide code examples and try to formulate your question as precisely as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is an XSLT 1.0 solution** (XSLT 2.0 has much more powerful features for string processing, such as regular expressions):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()">
   <xsl:variable name="vpostHref"
    select="substring-after(., 'href=')"/>

   <xsl:variable name="vhrefData1"
    select="substring($vpostHref,2)"/>

   <xsl:variable name="vhrefData2"
    select="substring($vhrefData1, 1,
                      string-length($vhrefData1)-1
                      )"/>

   <xsl:call-template name="stripBackwards">
    <xsl:with-param name="pText"
      select="$vhrefData2"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pTextLength"
     select="string-length($vhrefData2)"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="stripBackwards">
  <xsl:param name="pText"/>
  <xsl:param name="pStopChar" select="'\'"/>
  <xsl:param name="pTextLength"/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, $pStopChar))">
     <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:variable name="vLastChar"
       select="substring($pText,$pTextLength,1)"/>
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="$vLastChar = $pStopChar">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($pText,1,$pTextLength -1)"/>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="stripBackwards">
          <xsl:with-param name="pText"
           select="substring($pText,1,$pTextLength -1)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pTextLength" select="$pTextLength -1"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pStopChar" select="$pStopChar"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href=".\Files\Style\test.xsl"?>
<t/>
```

**the correct result is produced**:

```
.\Files\Style
```